# Problems with installing utop for OCaml

Tags: ocaml, utop

I can't install utop because it requires lambda-term, but it seems like I can't install lambda-term because of some conflict.

[image: Problem on Terminal]

Comment: I'm not sure why `react` and `lwt_react` conflict. I would suggest you uninstall both and try installing `utop` again, but I'll let someone more knowledgeable explain what is going on.

Comment: Try executing `eval $(opam config env)` to make sure your terminal is using the right environment variables.